# Where do I change the ios bundle identifier in ionic2?

Tags: angular, ionic2

i try to change the bundle identifier in my angular2 and ionic2 app. In ionic1 there was a config.xml with

```
<widget id="com.bundle.identifier" version="2.0" ...>
```

in it. Where do i find that in ionic2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the config.xml under root folder of that project.

Comment: that was too easy :-o